# Terminal settings (GCC,SQL-database,g++,java)

Tags: mysql, backup, gnome-terminal

I have dual booted my laptop with windows and Ubuntu and now my Ubuntu is getting slower day by day.

My question is, if I reinstall my Ubuntu (single booting to Ubuntu(removing dual boot)) then my terminal settings like GCC,g++,Mysql database (very important),etc will be there or I have to create(install) them again on newly installed UBUNTU.

I am currently signed in to my Ubuntu account.

Comment: If you are going to remove your Windows partition and wipe the system to re-install Ubuntu using the full disk, why would any of your existing data survive? If your MySQL databases are sitting on a dedicated partition, then they may persist over a re-installation, but you may run into issues when re-attaching existing database files to a new MySQL installation. If something is "very important", you should have backups. If you have backups, then wiping a system and starting over will take time, but not result in any data loss.

Comment: Thank you @Matigo for your guidance.Can you suggest me some software or methods so that all my packages stored in terminal can be backed up?